# How do I get output parameters using asp from a exec sproc_name

Tags: stored-procedures, asp-classic, sql-server-2000

In asp I'm trying to open a query that contains the exec to a sproc.  It works fine with some input params and no output params.  But I was trying to create some output params.  How do I get the output params from my result set or should I try it a different way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this article on doing exactly what you want.  The first example is reading from a record set and the second example is using output parameters.  It shows how to create them and how to set and read their values with ADO:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa224819(v=sql.80).aspx